# Linux qemu boot aarch64 disk image

Tags: linux, debian, qemu, arm64

My host machine is :

```
Linux my-laptop 5.15.0-40-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 15 12:54:21 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux   

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

how do you emulate aarch64 disk image with qemu ?
i want to run this [debian-11-generic-arm64.qcow2](https://cloud.debian.org/images/cloud/bullseye/latest/debian-11-generic-arm64.qcow2)
According to [debian document](https://wiki.debian.org/Arm64Qemu), this command should work :

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -m 2G -M virt -cpu max \
  -bios /usr/share/qemu-efi-aarch64/QEMU_EFI.fd \
  -drive if=none,file=debian-11-generic-arm64.qcow2,id=hd0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 \
  -device e1000,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:5555-:22 \
```

but i jump to qemu console :

```
QEMU 6.2.0 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu)
```

this package installed :

```
ii  ipxe-qemu                                     1.21.1+git-20220113.fbbdc3926-0ubuntu1      all          PXE boot firmware - ROM images for qemu
ii  ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms                1.0.0+git-20150424.a25a16d-0ubuntu4         all          PXE boot firmware - Compat EFI ROM images for qemu
ii  qemu                                          1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.15                      amd64        fast processor emulator, dummy package
ii  qemu-block-extra                              1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.15                      amd64        extra block backend modules for qemu-system and qemu-utils
ii  qemu-efi-aarch64                              2022.02-3ubuntu0.22.04.1                    all          UEFI firmware for 64-bit ARM virtual machines
ii  qemu-efi-arm                                  2022.02-3ubuntu0.22.04.1                    all          UEFI firmware for 32-bit ARM virtual machines
ii  qemu-system-arm                               1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.15                      amd64        QEMU full system emulation binaries (arm)
ii  qemu-system-common                            1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.15                      amd64        QEMU full system emulation binaries (common files)
ii  qemu-system-data                              1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.15                      all          QEMU full system emulation (data files)
ii  qemu-system-gui                               1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.15                      amd64        QEMU full system emulation binaries (user interface and audio support)
ii  qemu-system-x86                               1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.15                      amd64        QEMU full system emulation binaries (x86)
ii  qemu-user-static                              1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.15                      amd64        QEMU user mode emulation binaries (static version)
ii  qemu-utils                                    1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.2                       amd64        QEMU utilities
```